# describe_db_instances fails with timeout

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have an RDS instance `my_instance` and a lambda with permissions to perform describe_db_instance on that instance. Both sit on the same VPC.

The RDS has a SC `my-security-group-rds` and lambda another security group `my-security-group-lambda`.

`my-security-group-lambda` has outbound rule without constraints. All protocols with IP 0.0.0.0/0.

`my-security-group-rds` has an inbound rule that allows any access from `my-security-group-lambda`.

Inside the lambda I perform `describe_db_instance(my_instance)` and this fails with a timeout connecting to `https://rds.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/`:

```
...
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 269, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/httpsession.py", line 377, in send
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://rds.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

What am I missing to provide access? Also, do I really need access to just perform describe instances? Note that the timeout is not to the url of the database but to the AWS system.

Comment: Are you running the lambda inside VPC?

Comment: Making an API call to AWS requires Internet access. It would appear that your AWS Lambda function is configured to connect to a subnet in a VPC. This would then require a NAT Gateway to access the Internet. Is there a particular reason why the function is configured to connect to a VPC? If not, then simply disconnect the Lambda function from the VPC and it will be able to access the Internet. The function will then likely work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a VPC endpoint that would provide access to my SG to AWS services. Without a need for public internet egress. See

https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/aws-lambda-vpc/#set-up-a-vpc-endpoint-for-your-aws-service

```
resources:
  Resources:
    SNSVPCEndpoint:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
      Properties: 
        PrivateDnsEnabled: True
        SecurityGroupIds: 
          - !GetAtt VpcEndpointSecurityGroup.GroupId
        ServiceName: 'com.amazonaws.us-east-1.sns'
        SubnetIds: 
          - <yourFirstSubnetId>
          - <yourSecondSubentId>
        VpcEndpointType: Interface
        VpcId: <yourVpcId>
    VpcEndpointSecurityGroup:
      Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref VPC
        GroupDescription: 'Security group for VPC Endpoint'
        SecurityGroupIngress:
          - IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: 443
            ToPort: 443
            SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt VpcEndpointLambdaSecurityGroup.GroupId
    VpcEndpointLambdaSecurityGroup:
      Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
      Properties:
        VpcId: <yourVpcId>
        GroupDescription: 'Security group for VPC Endpoint Lambda'
```